# Import lazy component on sidenav menu

Tags: angular, ionic3

My app is using lazy loading but I have components loaded in `app.module` becase I need them anyway by default but most of them are loaded on different pages/components.

This is `side-menu.html`:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <login></login>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <language-change></language-change>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

`login` is loaded by default because the user will have to login always so this component works on the side menu.

`language-change` is only loaded when I need it and it works on other pages but not here. This is `side-menu.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPageModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { SideMenuPage } from "./side-menu";
import { LanguageChangeComponentModule } from "../../components/language-change/language-change.module";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [SideMenuPage],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(SideMenuPage),
        LanguageChangeComponentModule
    ],
    exports: [SideMenuPage],
    entryComponents: [SideMenuPage]
})
export class SideMenuPageModule { }
```

`language-change.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LanguageChangeComponent } from './language-change';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [LanguageChangeComponent],
    imports: [
        IonicModule
    ],
    exports: [LanguageChangeComponent],
    entryComponents: [LanguageChangeComponent]
})
export class LanguageChangeComponentModule { }
```

`side-menu.module`:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { IonicPageModule } from "ionic-angular";
import { SideMenuPage } from "./side-menu";
import { LanguageChangeComponentModule } from "../../components/language-change/language-change.module";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [SideMenuPage],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(SideMenuPage),
        LanguageChangeComponentModule
    ],
    exports: [SideMenuPage],
    entryComponents: [SideMenuPage]
})
export class SideMenuPageModule { }
```

I got the classic

> 'language-change' is not a known element

Comment: Can you post your `LanguageChangeComponentModule` typescript file? I assume you didnt export `LanguageChangeComponent` on the module

Comment: I did. Updated.

Comment: can you post side menu routing module

Comment: done @arunkumar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the `language-change` component name is `LanguageChangeComponent`.

Check if you are declaring and exporting `LanguageChangeComponent` from `LanguageChangeComponentModule`.

```
@NgModule({
   //....
   declarations : [LanguageChangeComponent],
   exports :  [LanguageChangeComponent]
   //...
 })
class LanguageChangeComponentModule{

}
```

If you want to avail this Component in entire application, you can `import` and `export` `LanguageChangeComponentModule` into `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LanguageChangeComponentModule
    ],
    exports: [LanguageChangeComponentModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If you want to use it in certain Module then you can import it into that Module instead of AppModule.

Comment: Updated question. I've got that on my module

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: As commented this is a lazy loaded component and I don't need it loaded on app.module

Comment: That is pretty easy. You can simply import the  LanguageChangeComponentModule into the module wherever this component is used. Remove it from app.module.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. It works on any other component but it's like doesn't work just for the side menu. I updated answer again with side-menu.module

Comment: I don't see any other reason why it shouldn't work. You just remove `entryComponents: [LanguageChangeComponent]` and check if has any impact.

Comment: from where exactly?

Comment: from `LanguageChangeComponentModule`

Comment: still same problem

Comment: It would be easier and quicker way to fix if you can stackblitz demo.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to prepare something. In the meantime, any more ideas?

Comment: Its hard to tell from the snippet you provided here. Things are looking fine so lets check in stackblitz.

Comment: I'm trying to use lazy loading on that page but it doesn't seem to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bp9eyj I also tried an already created lazy loading project but same problem with "Invalid link": https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-page-lazy-loading-test. Any other page I can try with?

Comment: Go to stackblitz.com and select Angular project, it will create a sample project for you.

Comment: I created the one the first link like that using Ionic. The problem here is more related to side-nave, which is an Ionic more related component

Comment: The issue was with Component selector. In `LanguageChangeComponent` you have declared the selector as `app-language-change` however while using it you had mentioned `language-change`. Here is the working copy here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-untdxb

Comment: Yes, it seems that stackblitz added `app-`. However you're not lazy loading it. You added the module to app.module. If you removed the component from side-nav.module still working because it's not lazy loaded

Comment: About stackblitz and Ionic + lazy loading it won't work there (https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/632) so if you know any other website let me know

Comment: I had removed `LanguageChangeModule` from AppModule, still it is working. Are you refering to any other Module ?

Comment: Got confused. Ok, so basically `LanguageChangeComponentModule` inside home.module `exports` makes the change. Even if I remove the component from `side-nav.module` it still working. Why is this? I'm trying to get this working in the meantime on my project

Comment: `LanguageChangeComponentModule` was exported inside `home.module` for testing however that is not required. I have updated the link.

Comment: try adding now the component on side-nave.html. I did and it doesn't work. Also HomePage is loaded on app.module. You could move it to app.component as 'HomePage'

Comment: yes, app.component as 'HomePage' not working. Looks like the issue you had mention is the valid and there is no fix this yet.

Comment: Ok, so at the moment the only different to my project is that I have HomePage lazy loaded. Apart from this the error remains the same: if you go to side-nave.html and uncomment that you'll get the issue UNLESS you add `exports: [HomePage, LanguageChangeComponent]` in home.module. Even when you do this you can remove the component references inside `side-nav.module`. Is there any difference here when you load the main page from app.module VS lazy loading? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mnji7z

Comment: I don't see the error in the link you provided. Its working fine. there is no error.

Comment: There is no error unless you remove it from `export` in `home.module`. Try again

Comment: did you get a chance to have a look?

Comment: It looks like the issue with your project structure. Please move your `pages` folder inside `app` folder.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's just a reference. However, on my real project pages folder is inside app. At the end I "fixed" it loading `language-change` in `core.module`. I know it's not lazy loaded but it needs to much effort for just a simple piece of code. Thanks for you help anyway